# Add constraints to a UIViewController does not work

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Simple question, but I don't get the answer of satisfaction. 
So, I want to add some constraints to my added UIViewController via code.

Thank you so much :)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

let imageLogoName = "pictureIsInAssets"
let imageLogo = UIImage(named: imageLogoName)
let imageLogoView = UIImageView(image: imageLogo!)

setImageContraints()
}



func setImageContraints(){

imageLogoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageLogoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true
imageLogoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true
imageLogoView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageLogoView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 28).isActive = true
    }
```

In the func setImageContraints:
Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'imageLogoView'

Comment: You might want to replace the `let imageLogoView` in `viewDidLoad` with `imageLogoView` as I think you're intending to set your instance variable

Answer (score 1):

You are using variable `imageLogoView` outside of it's visibility/life cycle scope. You should have an instance variable instead:

```
class SomeViewController {
    var imageLogoView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // <-- notice this

        let imageLogoName = "pictureIsInAssets"
        let imageLogo = UIImage(named: imageLogoName)
        self.imageLogoView = UIImageView(image: imageLogo!)

        setImageContraints()
    }
}
```

or simpler:

```
class SomeViewController {
    let imageLogoView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "pictureIsInAssets"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // <-- notice this

        setImageContraints()
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add the image view to the view.

Comment: Your are a genius. As you noticed, I am new to swift: why did you write "self.imageLogoView = ..." instead of "imageLogoView = ..." ?

Comment: It's just a personal preference. `self` can be omitted here it's just indicates that you are accessing the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

imageLogoView is no global variable.

You have to declare it like that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
   let imageLogoView: UIImageView!


   override func viewDidLoad() {

   let imageLogoName = "pictureIsInAssets"
   let imageLogo = UIImage(named: imageLogoName)
   imageLogoView = UIImageView(image: imageLogo!)

   setImageContraints()
   }
}
```

Comment: if you declare the imageLogoView as a `let` constant it should be initialized in an initializer. you should use `var` instead.